# Oracle SQL procedures header layout

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, header, row

so i'm trying to style my table like this: [Style like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BKCVf.jpg)

But mine is looking like this: [My one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/moGIW.jpg)

How do I straighten the rows up so it matches to the headings?

Here is my code within "begin":

```
BEGIN
OPEN e_cursor2;
dbms_output.put_line('' || chr(10));
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ORDER LINE DETAILS: ');
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Line#   ' || 'Make          ' || 'Model           ' || 'Year    ' || 'QTY    ' || 'Item Price     ' || 'SUBTOTAL');
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('-----  ' || ' ----        ' || '  -----  ' || '         ----  ' || '  ---  ' || '  ----------  ' || '   --------  ');
dbms_output.put_line('' || chr(10));
LOOP
FETCH e_cursor2 INTO e_row2;
EXIT WHEN e_cursor2%NOTFOUND;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(e_cursor2%rowcount || '       ' || chr(32) || e_row2.i_make || '        ' ||e_row2.i_model || '         ' || 
                                          e_row2.i_year || '        ' || e_row2.ol_qty || '       ' ||e_row2.i_price || '        ' ||e_row2.i_price);
END LOOP;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

I tend to agree with the other answer so far, to use HTML formatting in SQL*Plus but since you are asking, I will say how to do it the way you are asking.  You need to have the size of each column fixed and padded out with lpad or rpad.  Something like this will do what you need:

```
BEGIN
OPEN e_cursor2;
dbms_output.put_line('' || chr(10));
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ORDER LINE DETAILS: ');
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(rpad('Line#',8) || rpad('Make',8) || rpad('Model',14) || rpad('Year',7) || rpad('QTY',8) || rpad('Item Price',14) || rpad('SUBTOTAL',10));
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(rpad('-----',8) || rpad('----',8) || rpad('-----',14) || rpad('    ',7) || rpad('---',8) || rpad('----------',14) || rpad('--------',10));
dbms_output.put_line('' || chr(10));
LOOP
FETCH e_cursor2 INTO e_row2;
EXIT WHEN e_cursor2%NOTFOUND;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(rpad(e_cursor2%rowcount,8) ||
                     rpad(e_row2.i_make,8)      ||
                     rpad(e_row2.i_model,14)    ||
                     rpad(e_row2.i_year,7)      ||
                     rpad(e_row2.ol_qty,8)      ||
                     rpad(e_row2.i_price,14)    ||
                     rpad(e_row2.i_price,10)     );
END LOOP;
```

You get the idea even though I probably made a few mistakes.  I went ahead and padded each of the title row elements so everything would line up.  Making everything come out correctly this way takes forever but it is great fun when it all comes together.

Comment: Correct in principle. The convention is to `rpad()` strings and column headings but `lpad()` numbers (dates obviously are a fixed length). Another thing is to distinguish the column separation spacing from the length of individual columns, as that makes it easier to improve the layout.

Answer (score 0):

You are truing to do fixed length formatting, you can of course brute force it with string functions (e.g. lpad(to_char(numeric column) ...

Personally, I would not choose PL/SQL for this, but rather use HTML formatting from SQL*Plus.